# extjs 2.3 grid fails on store update

Tags: javascript, extjs

First time posting, have only started using extjs 2.3 (at my work) and have run into a strange issue.  Basically I have an option for a user to get SLD (straight line distance) between a location they have selected and a number of predefined locations, so the users clicks the SLD button, a new window opens which does the following, loads predefined locations into a jsonstore, links this store into a grid in the new window, when the store is created I also send a request to googles directions service to return the driving distance between the locations, on callback I add this data to store which in turns updates the grid.

The issue I see is, the first time the SLD button is clicked, the grid displays the information, and then the google callback adds the extra data into the store and I can see this displayed on the grid.  I have a back button on the window, which when clicked returns the user to the menu window, destroys the SLD window and empties the store, so there is no trace of the SLD window any more.  The issue will happen now when I click the SLD button again on the main menu, I can see the grid with data but now when the google callback returns and updates the store I see that the cells look like they have been edited and not saved.

On my production machine this issue does not happen when I use Firefox or Chrome, only happens on IE, however I have wrote a small jsFiddle to reproduce the issue and now get the issue to happen on Chrome when I run the test.

I can't understand how it can work correctly the first time, then the second time have this issue, and basically its running the same code as the first time!

This is what my test looks like, have added dummy data and simplified things to reproduce issue

```
var testData = [
    {'name': 'home', 'distance': 16.5, 'driving_distance': 0 },
    {'name': 'work', 'distance': 35.2, 'driving_distance': 0 },
    {'name': 'gym', 'distance': 12.8, 'driving_distance': 0 },
];

var locations;

// create store and load it with data
function createStore() {

    locations = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        data: testData,
        sortInfo: {
            field: 'distance',
            direction: 'ASC'
        },
        fields: [
            { name: 'name' },
            { name: 'distance', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'driving_distance', type: 'float' }
        ]
    });

    var myLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng( '55.033778', '-7.125324' );
    var anyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng( '54.972441', '-7.345526' );
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng( '55.033778', '-7.125324' ),
        destination: anyLocation,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    // get driving distance from myLocation to anyLocation and update locations store
    for ( var x = 0; x < locations.data.length; x++ )
    {
        // call directions service
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            // do stuff if we get a result
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                // update store items to use same value just for text purposes
                var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                distance = distance / 1000;

                // update on return call even though it updating the same thing 3 times
                locations.data.items[0].set('driving_distance', distance.toFixed(1));
                locations.data.items[1].set('driving_distance', (distance + 10.1).toFixed(1) );
                locations.data.items[2].set('driving_distance', (distance + 23.3).toFixed(1) );
                locations.commitChanges();
            }
        });
    }
}

new Ext.Window ({
    // menu normally consists of a combo box in which a user can select SLD
    title: 'Menu - cut down',
    id: 'rightClickWindow',
    headerPosition: 'left',
    scope: this,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'SLD',
        id: 'SLDButton',
        handler: function () {
            // hide menu window
            Ext.getCmp('rightClickWindow').hide();
            // create store
            createStore();
            // create SLD window
            new Ext.Window ({
                title: 'SLD',
                id: 'createSLDWindow',
                headerPosition: 'left',
                width: 450,
                scope: this,
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'grid',
                        id: 'SLDGrid',
                        singleSelect: true,
                        store: locations,
                        columns: [
                            {id: 'name', header: 'Location', width: 160, sortable: false, dataIndex: 'name'},
                            {header: 'SLD', width: 80, align: 'center', sortable: false, renderer: 'distance', dataIndex: 'distance'},
                            {header: 'Driving Distance', width: 90, align: 'center', sortable: false, renderer: 'driving_distance', dataIndex: 'driving_distance'}],
                        stripeRows: true,
                        autoExpandColumn: 'name',
                        enableHdMenu: false,
                        height: 250,
                        header: false
                } ],
                buttons: [{
                        text: 'Back',
                        id: 'SLDBackButton',
                        handler: function () {
                            // destroy SLD window
                            Ext.getCmp('createSLDWindow').destroy();
                            // show menu window
                            Ext.getCmp('rightClickWindow').show();
                            // destroy store
                            locations.loadData([],false);
                        }
                }],
                listeners: {
                    close: function (form) {
                        // destory everything
                        Ext.getCmp('createSLDWindow').destroy();
                        Ext.getCmp('rightClickWindow').destroy();
                        // destroy store
                        locations.loadData([],false);
                    }
                }
            }).show();
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UDkDY/74/

to reproduce click SLD -> back -> SLD

Comment: one question, does google service returns JSON data?

Comment: in this example it is JSON, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses

Comment: not looking good for an answer/suggestion!

Comment: to tell the truth, I tried several things but no success, sorry about that.

Comment: it is a tricky one, thanks for having a look at it.  I did try not destroying the SLD window but just hiding it, seems to behave better that way, but by doing so it introduced another issue where the store would update and fire update event but the grid didn't update its view even if I called view.refesh()

Comment: don't try `refresh()`, instead of that try store's `reload` method. As you said, if you destroy the window you should create same window manually. If I am not mistaken, your problem related with `createStore` method.

Comment: I tried disabling the store commit when google directions service returns just to see if it would still cause the issue and it didn't, so that lets me think that when the directions service returns and I commit to the store this is where the issue happens, the grid must have trouble with the new data

Comment: On second time SLD click, I am getting ERROR : 

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'addClass': object is null or undefined 
ext-all.js, line 2173 character 134


So If you can attach ext-all-debug.js I can go through it and tell you exactly what may be problem.

Because of this error only it is not able to apply cell CSS I guess !

Comment: As per current update :
in insertRows of View forst time we are getting true for this.hasRows();

but in second time and all we are getting false. That means rows are not created yet .

Comment: thanks for your reply, I dumped the ext-all.js into http://jsfiddle.net/5cLaT/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the way you update the values :
you send 3 requests (one for each line in the grid), but on the callback of each request you update ALL the lines (when you should only update the line corresponding to the request).

Example :
http://jsfiddle.net/xer0d0he/

```
-
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I'll be reworking this functionality into ExtJS 5.1.2 in the coming weeks so I'll bear in mind what you have suggested, will update back when complete, thanks